# What are the rendering options for timeline animations in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sld, animation, timemanager

I want to animate a shapefile that has a timeline (DATE) attribute using QGIS.
The [TimeManager] plugin (http://anitagraser.com/projects/time-manager/) has been installed and provides sufficient control to step down the dbf rows as expected.

However, the simple on/off display of each frame's features is not very attractive or sensible.

I want to be able to add controls for fading (to allow a feature fade to transparent over xx time) and for showing cumulative (leave previous features visible).

Is anyone aware of a plugin or styling strategy that might help improve these animations?

Comment: Not sure but perhaps this post might help a little: [Trajectory animations with fadeout effect](http://anitagraser.com/2015/05/08/trajectory-animations-with-fadeout-effect/)

Comment: Hey that's a great help, thanks. My data is polygon fills: I will give it a try and see if the same styling strategy will work there as well.

Comment: Awesome buddy! I haven't tested it with polygons but I don't see why it shouldn't work. But good luck and hope you get the results you're looking for :)